# No callback for Google Maps panorama request

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-street-view

I am new to the Google Maps SDK. I wrote a little test app that is able to show a map with routing, and a streetView panorama. This works fine, i.e. everything (the Google account, the API key, etc.) is probably setup correctly.
I now tried to get streetView pano metadata using

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let panoramaService = GMSPanoramaService()
    panoramaService.requestPanoramaNearCoordinate(start) { pano, error in
        guard error == nil else { fatalError() }
    }
}
```

where `start` ist some coordinate.
I set breakpoints at the `requestPanoramaNearCoordinate` call, and at the `guard` statement in the callback. The 1st breakpoint is reached, but the 2nd not, i.e. **there is no callback**.
What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was my fault:
I initialized `panoramaService` as a variable **local to the async block**.
As soon as `requestPanoramaNearCoordinate` was executed, this variable was deallocated, and the completion block was thus not called.
The correct way is to declare `let panoramaService` as a property that is not deallocated. Then, the completion block is called, as expected.